# SQL Server redesign to reduce disk space

Tags: sql-server, database

We have an SQL Data Base that will be redesign. We are going to change some column types from INT to TINYINT. With this transformation we can reduce the length in disk of the data base or this transformation will not reduce disk space considerably? The data base version is SQL Server 2008 R2 32bits.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2004. However, the only recent one that had `R2` in it's name was 2008 R2.

Comment: And it depends on the existing size of the rows - are there any variable length columns in the table(s)? Either way, you have to compute the size on disk of each row, then compute the size on disk of the proposed change rows, and then work out whether more rows will fit on each page or not.

Comment: Did you compare the cost of the time to do the redesign to the cost of just buying/replacing more disk? If disk space is the only upside (memory may also be, or index size), it's worth calculating upfront.

Comment: The redesign is not just for reduce the disk space. We must to build a new application using the old data. It is just an opportunity to reduce space and optimize performance.

Comment: The columns to change are primary keys that are used as foreigner keys in another tables. The tables have in average 20000 registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are going to change some column types from INT to TINYINT.

Note 1 (my point of view): **The real problem isn't about storage on disk but about buffer pool.**

Note 2: Choosing the right data type for a column (ex. `MyColumn`) influences the size of following database structures:

1. *First* the heap/clustered index size and *then*
2. {Non-clustered index|xml index|spatial index} size if `MyColumn` if part if clustered index key because clustered index key is duplicated in every non-clustered index row, is duplicated in every primary [xml index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx) (I'm not 100% sure: and in every secondary xml 'FOR PROPERTY' index) and is duplicated in every [spatial index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx).
3. Non-clustered index size if `MyColumn` is part of index (as a key or as a covered column (SQL2005+, see `CREATE ... INDEX ... ON ... INCLUDE()`).
4. If `MyColumn` has {PRIMARY KEY constraint|UNIQUE constraint+NOT NULL|UNIQUE index+NOT NULL} and if there are foreign keys that reference `MyColumn` then those FKs must have the same data type, max length, precision, scale and collation like `MyColumn` (PK/UQ). Of course, these FKs can be, also, indexed (clustered/non-clustered index).
5. If `MyColumn` is included in a indexed view. Indexed views can have unique clustered and non-clustered indices so, `MyColumn` can be duplicated again.
6. If `MyColumn` has {a PRIMARY KEY constraint|a UNIQUE constraint+NOT NULL|a UNIQUE index+NOT NULL} them is duplicated in every [full-text index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) that references this column (see `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ... KEY unique_index_name`).
7. Topic non-covered: column-store indices (SQL2012+).

So, yes, changing the data type for some columns might have a big impact. You can use this script:

```
SELECT  i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name, i.type_desc, ips.page_count, ips.*
FROM    sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS ips ON i.object_id = ips.object_id AND i.index_id = ips.index_id
WHERE   i.name IN (
    N'PK_PurchaseOrderHeader_PurchaseOrderID', ...
)
ORDER BY i.object_id, i.index_id;
```

to find out how many pages have every {heap structure|index} before and after data type change.

Note 3: If you have `Enterprise Edition` then you could compress data ([link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx), [link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

It will reduce the row size by 3 bytes for each column you change from INT to TINYINT. You may need to reclaim the space manually afterward though. Rebuilding the clustered index will do this.

Comment: @miguelbgouveia you could run the shrink command afterwards to reduce the size of the physical *.mdf file, but that does fragment your indexes and I'd advise against it unless you're really short on disk space. The advantage of reducing row size is that more rows fit into a data page, and so less disk IO is needed for a long read.